# Nativescript + Angular2: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat <filename>

Tags: npm, angular2-nativescript

I tried to run my app in the emulator and got the following error:

```
ShellJS: internal error
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a post [1] suggesting to clear the cache witch `npm cache clear` ... it worked for me.

[1] https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10826#issuecomment-165124144

Comment: Unfortunately, this was only a temporary success.